# I need to add code that counts number of unique words in the sentence in this piece of code

Tags: python

```
x = raw_input()
words = x.split()
words.sort()
for word in words:
    print(word.lower())
```

this is a piece of code which inputs a sentence and sorts it's word to dictionary order. In the output I also want to print the number of unique words in that sentence. How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: What is dictionary order? Also, show a sample input, expected output and explain what problems you are having in your own code. How is your code currently running right now that does not meet the expected behaviour.

Comment: My guess is "dictionary order" means "alphabetical order", but yes we really need more clarification on this, please.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
x = raw_input()
words = x.split()
words.sort()
for word in words:
    print(word.lower())
print(len(set(words)))
```

As was so pleasantly pointed out in the comments there is no explanation, so here it goes. the `set()` method generates a set from the list. Sets can only have unique entries, therefore the `len()` method will provide the length of the unique set. Also pointed out in the comments, a set has a `len()` method so its not required to convert a set to a list as my previous answer had.

Comment: How does this help the OP or anyone else? Don't just dump code. If you are going to answer a question that shouldn't be answered in its current state, at least make it a good answer.

Comment: @idjaw This helps OP by answering the EXACT question that was asked.

Comment: sets also have the `len()` method implemenented. You do not have to convert to list to get the size. Also you can mention that the conversion to set automatically removes the duplicate entries so that it does not feel like magic to the OP or anyone else.

Comment: @TheDude With NO explanation. That is the point of my comment...It's just a code dump answer.

Comment: However, this does not actually give unique words. This removes duplicate words. I think the OP is actually looking for words that only showed up once in the string. But, since the explanation is not very clear and the OP has not clarified anything beyond their original question, it's still up in the air.

Comment: @idjaw I am not sure I understand what the difference between a list of unique words and a list with all duplicate words removed is... "I also want to print the NUMBER of unique words" not the unique words themselves.

Comment: @TheDude `"The dog ate bacon and then cheerios and then a potato"`. So, in that sentence everything except `and` and `then` only appears once in the sentence. I think that is what OP means by unique. However, since there still isn't clarification, it *could* be a matter of removing duplicates. But I think it is a matter of pulling out words that only appeared once in the string. This is why answering these questions is a toss up. We never know what the OP *really* means until we finally get them to provide better examples.

Comment: @idjaw Good point. I'll leave my answer until it becomes clearer, but it may need updated.

Comment: @TheDude Agreed. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects)

```
from collections import Counter

words = ["foo", "bar", "bar"]
counts = Counter(words)
print counts
# Counter({"foo": 1, "bar": 2})
unique_words = [word for word in counts if counts[word] == 1]
print unique_words
# ["foo"]
```

> A Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects. It is an unordered collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values.

Comment: Might want to explain what Counter is (even if it's obvious) and what it returns

Comment: Also, I don't know if your intention is to leave some parts out of the final solution, but that will not give you unique counts by default. There is *some* logic remaining to actually get the unique count.

Comment: not sure what logic ur referring to seems to work just fine for me.

Comment: @marcusshep Outputting the unique words. The missing logic would be to print out the words that have a count of 1.

Comment: @marcusshep FYI - We *still* don't really know which direction OP is going, though. For example, it could be to bring out words that have a count of 1, or it could be to output the string with removing duplicates. I *think* it is the former, which in this case, your `Counter` solution would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to import any external modules. You can use 'set()', precisely:

`unique_num = len(set(words))
print unique_num`